# Custom blocking function in C++

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, events, sdl

I'm creating application model with three threads based on `while(true)` and a blocking function.

1. Event thread - waits for user input, blocked by SDL_WaitEvent
2. Socked thread - waits for data from server, blocked by blocking socket.
3. Render thread - renders data from buffer, not blocked.

I have a problem with rendering thread - i need a blocking function that will, for example, block until some paint event (defined by me and dispatched in one of other two threads) happens.
But I don't know how blocking functions work. I can, of course, create an `sleep()` loop, but such loop has fixed FPS takes resources even if nothing happens (I've already elaborated on that topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666812/prevent-sdl-program-from-consuming-extra-resources)). On the oher side, it does not display data immediatelly. This is not good for GUI application.

Comment: Whats about WaitForMultipleObject? It it not what you are looking for?

Comment: Looks good. Is there multiplatform version? Or at least, linux equivalent, so I can write one myself?

Comment: `WaitForMultipleObject` is a hack, because Windows didn't have conditional variables.  It's very nice when you're waiting for external events, like incoming data, but it's not really well designed for internal synchronization; it's too easy to get race conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using C++11, you can use `std::condition_variable` and
`std::mutex`:

```
void
waitForEvent()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock( myMutex );
    while ( ! externalCondition ) {
        myConditionVariable.wait( lock );
    }
}
```

To trigger the event:

```
void
setEvent()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock( myMutex );
    setExternalCondition();
}
```

On the other hand, you mention a GUI and a renderer.  You
*cannot* wait on an external condition in the GUI thread.  If
you need to be in the GUI thread for rendering, you'll have to
find out how to create a GUI event in your GUI manager, and post
the GUI event.

Comment: Well, this looks even better, but I have a few questions. First, what is `myMutex` variable? Then what are theese `<blah>` after variable definition. This is not the first time I see them. Quite similar, I see no definition of `myConditionVariable`. I'm sorry, but I'm beginner and I only understand very basic syntax.

Comment: `myMutex` and `myConditionVariable` are variables of type `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable`, respectively.  And the `<...>` are template specifications: you must have seen them a lot, any time you've used `std::vector`, for example.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen them with vector, and while I didn't understand them, I did my best to avoid vectors at all. Even if `myConditionVariable` and `myMutex` are of `std::mutex`, they don't just pop from the air, do they? I'm sorry for being so annoying, but to make working code, I need to know where to define theese, or, at least, understand whole problem.

Comment: @TomášZato Why do you avoid vectors?  The alternatives are usually more complicated.  As for the definitions, everything in `std::` is defined in a standard header.  You just have to include it. `<mutex>` and `<condition_variable>`, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

> Looks good. Is there multiplatform version? Or at least, linux
>   equivalent, so I can write one myself?

Take a look at this thread: [WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects equivalent in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719580/waitforsingleobject-and-waitformultipleobjects-equivalent-in-linux)

Stick to pthread_cond_timedwait and use clock_gettime. For example:

```
struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &ts);
ts.tv_sec += 10; // ten seconds
while (!some_condition && ret == 0)
    ret = pthread_cond_timedwait(&cond, &mutex, &ts);
```

Comment: Why the timed wait?  (And you might show where and when the mutext is handles.)