# Threads: When ones thread is running can you interact with the other?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency

So I'm learning about threads at the moment and I'm wondering how some things are handled. For example, say I have a program where one thread listens for input and another performs some calculation on a single processor. When the calculation thread is running, what happens if the user should press a button intended for the input thread? Won't the input get ignored by the input thread until it is switched to that specific thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends a good deal on how the input mechanism is implemented.  One easy-but-very-inelegant way to implement I/O is *continuous polling*... in that scenario, the input thread might sit in a loop, reading a hardware register over and over again, and when the value in the register changes from 0 to 1, the input thread would know that the button is pressed:

```
void inputThread()
{
   while(1)
   {
      if (some_register_indicates_the_button_is_pressed()) react();
   }
}
```

The problem with this method is that it's horribly inefficient -- the input thread is using billions of CPU cycles just checking the register over and over again.  In a multithreaded system running this code, the thread scheduler would switch the CPU between the busy-waiting input thread and the calculation thread every quantum (e.g. once every 10 milliseconds) so the input thread would use half of the CPU cycles and the calculation thread would use the other half.  In this system, if the input thread was running at the instant the user pressed the button, the input would be detected almost instantaneously, but if the calculation thread was running, the input  wouldn't be detected until the next time the input thread got to run, so there might be as much as 10mS delay.  (Worse, if the user released the button too soon, the input thread might never notice it was pressed at all)

An improvement over continuous polling is *scheduled polling*.  It works the same as above, except that instead of the input thread just polling in a loop, it polls once, then sleeps for a little while, then polls again:

```
void inputThread()
{
   while(1)
   {
      if (some_register_indicates_the_button_is_pressed()) react();
      usleep(3000);  // sleep for 30 milliseconds
   }
}
```

This is much less inefficient that the first case, since every time usleep() is called, the thread scheduler puts the input thread to sleep and the CPU is made immediately available for any other threads to use.  usleep() also sets a hardware timer, and when that hardware timer goes off (30 milliseconds later) it raises an interrupt.  The interrupt causes the CPU to leave off whatever it was doing and run the thread-scheduling code again, and the thread-scheduling code will (in most cases) realize that its time for usleep() to return, and wake up the input thread so it can do another iteration of its loop.  This still isn't perfect: the inputThread is still using a small amount of CPU on an ongoing basis -- not much, but if you do many instances of this it starts to add up.  Also, the problem of the thread being asleep the whole time the button is held down is still there, and potentially even more likely.

Which leads us to *interrupt-driven I/O*.  In this model, the input thread doesn't poll at all; instead it tells the OS to notify it when the button is pressed:

```
void inputThread()
{
   while(1)
   {
      sleep_until_button_is_pressed();
      react();
   }
}
```

The OS's notification facility, in turn, has to set things up so that the OS is notified when the button is pressed, so that the OS can wake up and notify the input thread.  The OS does this by telling the button's control hardware to generate an interrupt when the button is pressed; once that interrupt goes off, it works much like the timer interrupt in the previous example; the CPU runs the thread scheduler code, which sees that it's time to wake up the input thread, and lets the input thread run.  This mechanism has very nice properties:  (1) the input thread gets woken up ASAP when the button is pressed (there's no waiting around for the calculation thread to finish its quantum first), and (2) the input thread doesn't eat up any CPU cycles at all, except when the button is pushed.  Because of these advantages, it's this sort of mechanism that is used in modern computers for any non-trivial I/O.

Note that on a modern PC or Mac, there's much more going on than just two threads and a hardware button; e.g. there are dozens of hardware devices (keyboard, mouse, video card, hard drive, network card, sound card, etc) and dozens of programs running at once, and it's the operating system's job to mediate between them all as necessary.  Despite all that, the general principles are still the same; let's say that in your example the button the user clicked wasn't a physical button but an on-screen GUI button.  In that case, something like the following sequence of events would occur:

1. User's finger presses the left mouse button down
2. Mouse's internal hardware sends a mouse-button-pressed message over the USB cable to the computer's USB controller
3. Computer's USB controller generates an interrupt
4. Interrupt causes the CPU to break out of the calculation thread's code and run the OS's scheduler routine
5. The thread scheduler sees that the USB interrupt line indicates a USB event is ready, and responds by running the USB driver's interrupt handler code
6. USB driver's interrupt handler code reads in the event, sees that it is a mouse-button-pressed event, and passes it along to the window manager
7. Window manager knows which window has the focus, so it knows which program to forward the mouse-button-pressed event to
8. Window manager tells the OS to wake up the input thread associated with that window
9. Your input thread wakes up and calls react()

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on a single processor system, then yes.

Comment: ..but this will happen as soon as the input occurs, (on most OS, anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are multiple ways the thread can comunicate with each other. One of them is having global variable and use it as a buffer for communication beteen threads.
When you asked about button there must be a thread containing event loader loop. Within this thread, input won't be ignored according to my experience.

You can see some of my threads about this topic:
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14690990/custom-blocking-function-in-c), I was interested how to make 3 thread application that do communicate through events.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes, threads always interact. The problems start to appear when they interact in a non-predictable way. Every thread in a process has access to the entire process memory space, so changing memory in one thread may spoil the data for another thread.

Answer (score 1):

The thread waiting for user input will be made ready 'immediately'.  On most OS, threads that were waiting on I/O and have become ready are given a temporary priority boost and, even on a single-core CPU, will 'immediately' preempt another thread that was running at the same priority.

So, if a single-core CPU is running a calculation and another, waiting, thread of the same priority gets input, it will probably run straightaway.